# How to create a conversation list in Django chatting app

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset, django-messages

I am trying to add messaging functionality to my web app made in Django.

So far, I have managed to successfully send and receive messages from user to user.

But, now I have been stuck at showing all the conversation lists to the `inbox.html` page of the logged user.

I have tried different approaches that I can think of but can not get the expected result.

`models.py`

```
class Messaging(models.Model):
    sender = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='sender')
    receiver = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='receiver')
    message_text = models.TextField(max_length=360, verbose_name='Write Message')
    message_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.sender}\'s Message to {self.receiver}'
```

`viwes.py`
**Function to send and receive messages from user to user**

```
@login_required
def messageview(request, user_name):
    sender_user = request.user
    receiver_user = User.objects.get(username=user_name)
    message_list = Messaging.objects.filter(sender=sender_user, receiver=receiver_user).order_by('message_date') | \
                   Messaging.objects.filter(receiver=sender_user, sender=receiver_user).order_by('message_date')



    if request.method == 'POST':
        msg_text = request.POST.get('msg_text')
        messaging = Messaging()
        messaging.sender = sender_user
        messaging.receiver = receiver_user
        messaging.message_text = msg_text
        messaging.save()

        return redirect(request.META['HTTP_REFERER'])

    context = {
        'sender_user': sender_user,
        'receiver_user': receiver_user,
        'message_list': message_list,
    }
    return render(request, 'message.html', context)
```

Now I want to create an `inboxview` in `views.py` that will render all the conversation of the logged user.

Suppose I have two users in the database A and B, they have exchange 4 messages between them. What I want is to show the conversation as a list, which is in this case only one. For example, the logged user is A, he exchanges messages with user B and C. The inbox will show two rows. When user A clicks on either of the rows, he will be taken to the details message page corresponding to the user. It is kinds of like WhatsApp or messenger. I hope I can explain.

***Edited: Added example image for better understanding***

I am able to do this:

[image: Conversation]

I need help to do this:
[image: Conversation List]

Please guide me the way.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this.

This view will query the `Messaging` model and get all entries where `sender` or `receiver` is the logged in user.

```
@login_required
def inbox(request, user):
    # Get all the records where either sender OR receiver is the logged in user
    messages = Messaging.objects.filter(sender=request.user) | Messaging.objects.filter(receiver=request.user)

    context = {'messages': messages}

    return render(request, 'inbox.html', context)
```

*You can add any extra lines of code to the above code that suits your requirements.*

**inbox.html**

```
{% for message in messages %}
   # You can show your message details here
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I have tried this approach but this doesn't gives the solution.

Comment: What does this give ? And whats the expected outcome ?

Comment: Suppose I have two users in database A and B, they have exchange 4 message between them. With your approach I am getting those 4 message in my template. But what I want is to show the conversation as a list, which is in this case only one. For example logged user is A, he exchange message with user B and C. The inbox will show two rows. When user A clicks on either of rows, he will be taken to the details message page corresponding to the user. Kinds of like whatsapp or messenger. I hope I can explain.

Comment: I have edited the post. I hope that helps.